# What regular expression should I use to find the file name that does not contain the specified string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, filenames

I am trying to create a list of files being in a folder using a preg_match function. However, I would like to omit the files that contain a string of "_min" between their filename and their extensions. Filenames should only consist of alphanumeric and an underscore characters and extensions should be only jpg and gif.
For example:
`desc_125f.jpg` -> matched,
`desc#_56.jpg` -> not matched (contains #),
`bla_bla.gif` -> matched,
`bla_bla.png` -> not matched (extension is png),
`desc_125f_min.jpg` -> **not matched (contains _min between a filename and an extension)**,
`desc_min256.gif` -> matched (_min is not between a filename and an extension).
How should the regex pattern be?

I have tried that: `^\w+(?!_min)\.(jpg|gif)$` but it does not work as I expected because the `desc_125f_min.jpg` has been matched.

Comment: Please edit your question and state the complete rules for a matching file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that the `\w+` absorbs all the characters up to the `.`, and so the negative lookahead for `_min` always succeeds. You need to move the negative lookahead to the beginning of the regex:

```
^(?!.*_min\.)\w+\.(jpg|gif)$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EcsFN9/1)

Comment: I would never have thought it is necessary to move that to the beginning of the regex. It works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is rather, that you use a look**ahead** right before `.` where you actually want to look **behind**.

```
^\w+(?<!_min)\.(jpg|gif)$
```

See [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XdbgO0/1). For reducing backtracking make the [`\w` quantifier possessive](https://regex101.com/r/XdbgO0/2).